# user to choose how many records per page to be displayed without to loose the search query - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on project written in codeigniter, and I have fairly complex search form, after which I display the search results.

I would like to provide the users with possibility to choose how many records per page to be displayed.

I have created the combobox with options, and my idea was to make utility class, where I will create a function that will save this number in the database and redirect the user back to the same page. However, after the redirect, I will loose the user query, so we will have to make the search again. How can i prevent that?

If this helps, my sessions are stored in the database in ci_session table.

Any ideas will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: use SESSION or GET to persist search data

Comment: so you suggest that I must store the query as whole in the session and then call it back on the search results page, after saving the records per page variable...having in mind that I would like to avoid using get in codeigniter....

Comment: not the query but the search input values

Comment: i will try that to see how it will work. that way i could use the same function to save the per_page variable, and avoid creating new one. thanks. you can make your comment an answer, so I can accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass all the parameters of the search query (including how many results to show) as `GET` parameters.

It's not uncommon to see a url like `search.php?q=boats+cars&page=3&nr=30&filters=[1,2]`

If you store part of the data in a session, cookie or localstorage you're limiting the user to one search query. If you open two search queries, the latter one will override data for the first one, leading to a very strange search experience.

Comment: i was hoping to avoid get...don't like those sphagetti like queries in the address bar

Comment: You could always apply some rewrite magic to make the URL look nicer: `search/boats+cars/3/30/filters:1,2` but I wouldn't worry too much about it. You could also serialize and base64_encode, that will completely hide the contents, you just get a string like `cT1ib2F0cytjYXJzJnBhZ2U9MyZucj0zMCZmaWx0ZXJzPVsxLDJd`